# Github commit date and author date

Tags: git, github, timestamp

My git commit-date and author-date are different. I want to set the commit-date same as my author-date once and forever because changing past commits only won't be a permanent solution. Can someone suggest a command for the same?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I think upon reading this question is: *why do you care?*  This state of affairs—different commit and author dates—is normal under circumstances that are not at all unusual.

Note that a *new* commit you make *right now* will have the same two values for committer and author dates.  The two drift apart when:

- you use rebase or cherry-pick; or
- you use `git am` or similar to email commits around.

In these cases, Git will try to keep the original author and author-date to the extent that this seems reasonable, while making you the committer and "now" the committer date.  This is because *no commit can ever be changed*.  What make this commit *this* commit is the fact that you made it just now: you took some existing commit, made some time ago, and used it as the basis for making a new commit, that you made just now.  You didn't make this new commit yesterday, you made it now.

The new commit *must* have *something* different.  If it's 100% identical to the old commit in every way—a bit-for-bit exact copy—then it literally *is* the old commit, and nothing has changed.  You can preserve the committer date if something else has also changed, but is more logical to make the new commit with "now" as the date, to guarantee that enough is different to make it a different commit.

When using the `am`-based back end with `git rebase`, the `--committer-date-is-author-date` flag will set the committer date from the author date.  So if your dates are changing because of rebasing, you *can* use that flag.  (But that runs right into the "why bother" question.)

Other than what I just mentioned, there is nothing built in to Git here.  You could of course modify Git: there's nothing secret about how it makes commits, or its source code.

Comment: Thanks @torek for reaching out. The the issue is when I make commit for 16th sep (which is my author-date)t in github UI it show's 17th sept( which is my commit-date). Any suggestions for is problem will be highly appreciating

Comment: Is this a problem because it messes up your contribution graph, or for some other reason?  If the former, don't sweat it: it's not a measure of your self-worth.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @bk2204 , its effecting my project actually. If some command could help it will be helpful

Comment: You'd need to edit your question to explain why this is a problem for you, because right now, with what you've given us, there is no solution to your problem other than you building your own custom version of Git.  If you have a different goal, please explain it in your question so we can help with a suitable answer.